# Grouping data based on column value difference

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table **user_work_details** with two columns:  USER_ID, START_TIME

START_TIME is in milliseconds (epoch), so writing actual time on side

```
  USER_ID     START_TIME 
-----------------------------
    1         1518210035904        Feb 9,  2018 9:00:35 PM
    1         1518307236904        Feb 9,  2018 9:00:35 PM
    1         1519048475905        Feb 19, 2018 1:54:35 PM
    2         1518400835906        Feb 12, 2018 2:00:35 AM
    2         1518400837906        Feb 9,  2018 9:00:37 AM
    3         1518494435907        Feb 13, 2018 4:00:35 AM
```

I need to group records according to difference in their START_TIME values. All records are to be grouped according to 5 minutes difference. So, the output should be:

```
  USER_ID     START_TIME         DIFF
--------------------------------------
    1         1518210035904      0
    1         1518307236904      0
    1         1519048475905      1
    2         1518400835906      2
    2         1518400837906      2
    3         1518494435907      3
```

DIFF will have same values if USER_ID is same or difference between two times is less than 5 mins. Also, DIFF needs to increase for every change.

I tried the above by using LAG() like this:

```
SELECT
"USER_ID",
"START_TIME",
CASE WHEN "START_TIME" - LAG("START_TIME", 1, "START_TIME") OVER 
(PARTITION BY "USER_ID" ORDER BY "START_TIME") > 60000 
THEN 1  
ELSE 0 
END AS DIFF
FROM "user_work_details"
order by "USER_ID", "START_TIME"
```

This query returns following output:

```
  USER_ID     START_TIME         DIFF
--------------------------------------
    1         1518210035904      0
    1         1518307236904      1
    1         1519048475905      1
    2         1518400835906      0
    2         1518400837906      1
    3         1518494435907      1
```

I need to increase DIFF only on change, some kind of manual counter increment. What should I do?

**Edit: Output values fixed, wrong values earlier**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` to define when a group starts and then use a cumulative sum to assign the diff:

```
SELECT uwd.*, SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY start_time) as diff
FROM (SELECT uwd.*
             ((START_TIME - LAG(START_TIME, 1, START_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY START_TIME) > 60000)::int) as flag
      FROM user_work_details uwd
     ) uwd;
```

I would recommend that you define your columns without double quotes.  Having to quote names just makes queries harder to write and to read.